# how to find largest number in a list using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion, typeerror

```
def find_highest(lst):
    if lst[0] < lst[-1]:
        return find_highest(lst.pop(0))
    elif lst[0] > lst[-1]:
        return find_highest(lst.pop())
    else: return lst
```

This code raises TypeError.
Can anyone tell why is this happening?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`).  Your [mre] should always show or state how you are executing your and give an example of the data being processed.

Comment: `lst.pop()` does not return a new list, it removes an element from the list in place and then returns the removed element. That means that your recursive call is getting a list element as `lst`, not an actual list, hence the error. In any case, I don't think your algorithm works as you expect, passing a list like `[1, 3, 1]` would return the same list.

Comment: When you printed stuff at different points in your code was there an obvious place where something was wrong? If you are using an IDE **now** is a good time to learn its debugging features - like setting breakpoints and examining values. Or you could spend a little time and get familiar with the built-in [Python debugger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pdb.html). Also, printing *stuff* at strategic points in your program can help you trace what is or isn't happening.

Comment: `Thank you guys.` - there may be some gals in the audience.  If you have solved your problem consider deleting your question or - [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You code has the problem that it will raise `IndexError`. You are pulling elements out of the list using `pop`, so at some point the list will be empty.

You should check for the list length.

Here you have the solution using a different approach - I still use `pop` but always on the same end of the list. -

```
def find_largest(target_list):

    # If the len of list is 0, we have consume all numbers.
    if len(target_list) == 0:
        return None

    # Just get a number from the list, no matter which ...
    number = target_list.pop()
    
    # ... then recursively call the function to get the largest among the
    # remaining numbers in the list.
    largest = find_largest(target_list)

    # Compare the number you pull out the list with the "largest" of the remaining and
    # keep the largest.
    if largest is None or number >= largest :
        return number
    
    return largest

if __name__ == "__main__":

    import random

    target_list = [random.randint(0, 10) for i in range(10)]
    print(f"Target list: {target_list}")

    largest = find_largest(target_list)
    print(f"Largest number: {largest}")
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution.

Comment: No problem glad to help.